# Circling a Cosmic string in less than 360 degrees for faster space travel?

Tags: space-travel, cosmic-string

I've red that Cosmic strings would warp space such that one could circle a cosmic string in less than 360 degrees. How few degrees?

If a ship were to circle a cosmic string in a spiral pattern, saving more and more distance on each wind, would it eventually move say, 1 lightyear in only 0.7 lightyears for the ship, or is the effect so negligible that it would hardly make any difference?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted; cosmic strings are part of mainstream cosmology research and the effect of a deficit angle described in the question is accurate (although I suppose it should say that one could circle a cosmic string in less than 360 degrees, instead of 180 degrees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a cosmic string creates a deficit angle. The amount of the deficit depends on the string tension. For values of the string tension consistent with current upper bounds, the deficit angle for a realistic cosmic string (if they exist) would be so small you would barely notice if you traveled around the string once, or even a few tens of thousands of times.

Backing up a little bit. You can think of a cosmic string geometry as being similar to a cone geometry. A cone can be represented as a plane with a 'wedge' removed, and the two edges of the wedge identified. The metric of a cone is the same as the flat space metric, but instead of identifying $\theta$ with $\theta+2\pi$ we identify $\theta$ with $\theta+2\pi-\alpha$, where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation about an axis perpendicular to the plane passing through the tip of the cone and $\alpha$ is the *deficit angle*. This "deficit angle" leads to a "conical singularity"; the curvature blows up at the tip of the cone.

Similarly, a cosmic string leads to a deficit angle. The "plane" in the above paragraph is a cross section of space slicing through the string at a point, and the "tip of the cone" is the intersection of the string and the plane. The deficit angle is related to the string tension (mass per unit length) $\mu$ by (example source, https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Gangui/Gangui4.html)
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \frac{8\pi G \mu}{c^2}
\end{equation}
According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string#Super-critical_cosmic_string), realistic cosmic strings are expected to have deficit angles at least 6 orders of magnitude smaller than the "critical value" of $2 \pi$, so as a loose upper bound let's say $\alpha < 10^{-5}\ {\rm rad}$. So it would take many windings of the string for a spaceship to notice any difference compared to the case where the string were not there.